# High CPU Utilization issue on Moqui instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, moqui

We are facing one problem of random High CPU utilization on Production Server which makes application Not Responding. And we need to restart the application again. We have done initial level diagnostic and couldn’t conclude.

We are using following configuration for Production Server

- Amazon EC2 8gb RAM(m4.large) ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Amazon RDS 2gb RAM(t2.small) Mysql database
- Java heap size -Xms2048M -Xmx4096
- Database Connection Pool size Minimum: 20 and Maximum: 150
- MaxThreads 100

Below two results are of **top** command

1) At 6:52:50 PM

```
KiB Mem :  8173968 total,  2100304 free,  4116436 used,  1957228 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,  1047676 free,      896 used.  3628092 avail Mem  
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
20698 root      20   0 6967736 3.827g  21808 S   3.0 49.1   6:52.50 java
```

2) At 6:53:36 PM

```
KiB Mem :  8173968 total,  2099000 free,  4116964 used,  1958004 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,  1047676 free,      896 used.  3627512 avail Mem 
PID   USER  PR  NI   VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM TIME+COMMAND                                                                           
20698 root 20   0 6967736 3.828g  21808 S  200.0 49.1  6:53.36 java
```

Note:

- Number of Concurrent users - 5 or 6 (at this time)
- Number of requests between 6:52:50 PM and 6:53:36 PM - 4

Results shows CPU utilization is increase drastically.

Any suggestion or direction which can lead to solution??

Additionally, following is the cpu utilization graph for last week.
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: What JVM is it, and what version of Moqui? What Java Servlet Container? Do you have a stack dump?

Comment: I assume the high CPU load is on the Moqui server, not the MySQL database server, yes?

Comment: JVM version - 1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation 25.151-b12)                                 Moqui version - 2.1.1-rc1

Comment: Moqui version - 2.1.1-rc1                                                                                   Java Servlet Container - Jetty                                                                           Yes, high CPU utilization on Moqui Server

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a stack trace, I'd guess that the problem is likely Jetty, as there have been recent documented bugs in Jetty causing the behaviour you describe on EC2 (do a google search on this.).  I would recommend you do a couple of stack trace dumps during 100% cpu, to confirm it is Jetty, then if you look at the Jetty documentation on this bug, hopefully you may find you simply need to update Jetty.